# running java ProcessBuilder using maven via jenkins not working

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have a maven project when I use a simple java method to run any process :

```java
public static String runInTerminalCommand(String[] cmdList) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmdList);
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    processBuilder.inheritIO();
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    return (output.lines().collect(Collectors.toList())).toString();
}
```

This return is empty , there is nothing inside.

can I have help please.
Thanks in advance

Comment: For what purpose do you use `runInTerminalCommand` within Jenkins? A Maven build does not need having a process builder?

Answer (score 0):

You have explicitly instructed the ProcessBuilder to send output to the JVM's standard output, instead of letting you capture it.

If you want to capture output, remove this line:

```
processBuilder.inheritIO();
```

Here's a complete example:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class Test {
  public static String runInTerminalCommand(boolean insertBug, String[] cmdList) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmdList);
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    if (insertBug) {
      processBuilder.inheritIO();
    }
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    return (output.lines().collect(Collectors.toList())).toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String[] cmd = { "echo", "Hello World" };

    System.out.println("With inheritIO:");
    System.out.println("Captured this text: " + runInTerminalCommand(true, cmd));
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Without inheritIO:");
    System.out.println("Captured this text: " + runInTerminalCommand(false, cmd));
  }
}
```

And here's what happens when you run it:

```
$ javac Test.java && java Test
With inheritIO:
Hello World
Captured this text: []

Without inheritIO:
Captured this text: [Hello World]
```

Comment: there is no effect to run the same method without this line

Comment: I included a complete example. Please try it out on your machine and verify

Comment: I think something is wrong with the configuration of jenkins. the method works fine in eclipse mode, but under jenkins it is always with an empty return. Do you have any idea that I should have jenkins level?